# How make that all objects .swf show first and last frame in same time?

Tags: php, flash, swfobject

***Good day.***

**Code:**

```
<ul class="inline">
<li>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="200">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="movie" value="http://mult.myjino.ru/public/flash/056_koshka_novii_god.swf">
<embed width="200" src="http://mult.myjino.ru/public/flash/056_koshka_novii_god.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</object>
<br>
<a href="/public/customize/edit/56" class="btn">Выбрать</a>
</li>

<li>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="200">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="movie" value="http://mult.myjino.ru/public/flash/000_medvediha_s_hlopushkoy.swf">
<embed width="200" src="http://mult.myjino.ru/public/flash/000_medvediha_s_hlopushkoy.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</object>
<br>
<a href="/public/customize/edit/50" class="btn">Выбрать</a>
</li>

<li>
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="200">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="movie" value="http://mult.myjino.ru/public/flash/020_zayac_shampan.swf">
<embed width="200" src="http://mult.myjino.ru/public/flash/020_zayac_shampan.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</object>
<br>
<a href="/public/customize/edit/20" class="btn">Выбрать</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

***Tell me please how make that all objects .swf show first and last frame in same time?***

***P.S.: need that all objects .swf has been one same time play...***